# field_info_field() deprecated, what's the equivalent?

Tags: 8, entities

In Drupal 8, `field_info_field()` has been deprecated.

I tried using `\Drupal\field\Field::fieldInfo()->getField('field_address')` and
`\Field::fieldInfo()->getField('field_address')`, but I get this error.

> Fatal error: Class 'Drupal\field\Field' not found in /var/www/drupal/modules/custom/foo/src/Controller/FooController.php

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [change record](https://www.drupal.org/node/2260037):

`field_info_field($entity_type, $field_name)` -> `FieldStorageConfig::loadByName($entity_type, $field_name)`

So you should use `\Drupal\field\Entity\FieldStorageConfig::loadByName` from now on.

It's probably best to use change records and issues on Drupal.org itself for docs at the moment, rather than 3rd party websites - I think they have slightly more chance of being right and kept up to date when something changes.

Comment: Sadly `\Drupal\field\Entity\FieldStorageConfig::loadByName('node', 'field_address')` is always empty for me. I dug into how `loadByName` works, and was able to extract the desired results by making this call: `\Drupal::config('field.storage.node.field_address')->get()`

Comment: That's wrong, you shouldn't be accessing config entity values directly through config. Doesn't make sense that loadByName() wouldn't work for you.

Comment: @Berdir is my example call to `loadByName()` in my previous comment correct? I've since removed the address module and then tried with a core field, that returns null as well.

Comment: How to modify the allowed values of a field using the above function ? am getting the allowed values of a field inside settings array when use **\Drupal\field\Entity\FieldStorageConfig::loadByName($entity_type, $field_name);**

Comment: This only works for user-created fields, not for native fields like 'uid'.

Comment: @donquixote I didn't know that but I guess it makes sense - maybe you can use [`EntityFieldManagerInterface::getBaseFieldDefinitions()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityFieldManagerInterface.php/function/EntityFieldManagerInterface%3A%3AgetBaseFieldDefinitions/8.2.x) (through the `entity_field.manager` service)?

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
use Drupal\field\Entity\FieldStorageConfig;
$field = FieldStorageConfig::loadByName('node', $field_name);
$allowed_values = options_allowed_values($field);
```

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for a D10 answer:

```
/** @var \Drupal\field\FieldStorageConfigInterface $field_config */
$field_config = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('field_storage_config')
  ->load(implode('.', [$entity_type, $entity_bundle, $field]));
```